# Having problems in Playing mp3 files in android

Tags: android, media-player

I am getting problems in playing audio(mp3) files this music files are like click sounds its residing at the raw folder, the problem is if there are many clicks at random intervals it throws an exception of nullPointer. It occurs anywhere when the click is done and anytime, is it related to the memory issue or MediaPlayer related problem, pls any suggestion will be appreceated.
Its simple media player object that i m calling, but its a games so on touch it plays the files, so in game i have many things to drag so i want a click sound at that time, sometime it works fine but when exceeds certain limit it throws null pointer exceptions. this is the code:

```
   MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.soun1);
   mp.start();
```

thats it:

Comment: put your code here so we can help you

Comment: i have posted my answer please try it

Comment: Are you by any chance creating a `MediaPlayer` object each time you want to play the sound?

Comment: yes. I tried by creating onCreate() too, but it throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, its [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), especially created when the concern of game like application where the sound files are used continuously, so here we should use SoundPool except of MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

**just try this ::**

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.soun1);
    mp.start();
```

**permission in manifest file:::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Why creating a default constructed MediaPlayer at all, if you are going to loose it right away?

Comment: why to declare permission for external storage, when everything is done on phone memory

Comment: as you know, you need to give this permission in to store data in sdcard same like this.this is like external part.

Answer (score 1):

To play media player...we need two classes..
let us suppose `mainactivity.java` is our first file..
here we define two buttons - `start_button` & `stop_button`

```
mButton_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent mIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,maservice.class);
        startService(mIntent);

    }
});
mButton_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent mIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,maservice.class);
        stopService(mIntent);

    }
});
```

maservice.java is our another java file. Here we define media player and also there should be 3 methods: onCreate(), onStart(), onDestroy().

Here is the code:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kyun);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent miIntent, int startid)
{
    super.onStart(miIntent, startid);
    mPlayer.start();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.stop();
}
```

We also have to define these java files in manifest file

- mainactivity.java is defined under activity tag
- but maservice.java is defined under service tag

Comment: in my case starting mediaPlayer in onCreate was the problem. I saw your code and fixed it by start in onStart. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the MP3 encoding. I tried with the same code, few work and few don't. So please try with a different one if it shows up the same error next time.

Comment: issue is not with mp3 encoding, its in fact, with the system , media player returns null when you play the sound constantly, each time creating instance of media player were causing the error, So especially for game, here android provides soundpool api.

Comment: android developer site says if object is null then it failed to create the object. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29

Comment: No..i wrote a 2 line code in the Activity, which just plays it once..the audio is like about 30 seconds. But it doesn't play at all. When the changed the mp3 to other, it played instantly.

Comment: I am not saying that it will create problem in playing mp3 files, i am saying for  playing any file frequently which is short but used frequently, then it will cause a problem in creating the object of media player. And you just telling about playing it once, it sometimes plays sometimes does not. And for your best knowledge, using the soundpool is useful for memory management too. Have a look on both api . Think yourself what you require. If you not using files frequently then media player and you have no memory issue is better for you, but was not good choice for me at that time.

Comment: maybe you right if you using more compressed version in substitute of mp3. I dont know why it was creating the problem and returning the null pointer exception, but got the solution as it was soundpool because my application was little game-type, so i used soundpool, cos it compresses the music files and loads into memory in once.